# Why this C program causing 'appcrash' error?

Tags: c, gcc

I am compiling and running a c program (gcc compiler) on windows 8, x64. When I try to run the executable, windows give error 'appcrash'. Can anyone help? Here is program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{

float a=5;
float *p1;
float* p2, p3;
p1=&a;
printf("%f \n %f \n %f \n",p1,&p1,*p1);
}
```

Comment: What had you expected it to print?

Comment: You should use %p, %p, %f in your printf

Comment: pointers aren't floats...

Comment: compiles and executes fine on gnu gcc 4.8.1

Comment: @mangusta That's the charm of undefined behaviour. "Executes fine" here is only for certain definitions of "fine".

Comment: @mangusta So it must be correct then!!

Comment: @mangusta it might, but it certainly isn't required to it will also have to do with the ABI, etc... printf is variadic so with x86_64 all arguments are pushed onto the stack, which is why it could work... but the C language doesn't require it to.

Comment: the program syntax is correct, i guess he needs to suppress warnings maybe

Comment: @mangusta Syntax is not the issue. He reports runtime error.

Comment: clang (the version that I am using) will parse the format string and create warnings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("%f \n %f \n %f \n",p1,&p1,*p1);
```

Your format string demands that you pass three floating point values. You only pass one, the last one. The other arguments that you pass are both pointers.

Thus your program invokes undefined behaviour. That means anything can happen. In this case you got lucky and encountered a runtime failure.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but if you wish to print those three arguments then you need to use `%p` for the pointers.

```
printf("%p\n%p\n%f\n", p1, &p1, *p1);
```

The best advice for you is to compile with warnings enabled. All modern compilers can find such mistakes for you.

Comment: I agree with your answer. However my gcc compiler on windows did not give single warning.

Comment: Did you ask it to give warnings

Comment: My experience it gives warnings with similar syntax as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to ask for warnings. Use -Wall

Answer (score 1):

My compiler reports the following warnings, that really should be errors. These warnings are the source of your crash.

```
[1:59pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] clang -Wall foo.c
foo.c:11:32: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'float *' [-Wformat]
    printf("%f \n %f \n %f \n",p1,&p1,*p1);
            ~~                 ^~
foo.c:11:35: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'float **' [-Wformat]
    printf("%f \n %f \n %f \n",p1,&p1,*p1);
                  ~~              ^~~
```

Comment: While I absolutely agree that this should be fixed, I don't understand why it crashed and not simply printed garbage.

Comment: @Maxime: Because it's undefined behavior. The compiler is not required to implement a sane processing path for this piece of code.

Comment: Your compiler is kind to emit warnings when it should keep quiet, as were doing old compilers. This is a library function call with a va list, in principle impossible to check. Add to that that the format information could very well be evaluated at run-time only.